# batch wmi for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, wmic

I'm having trouble using wmi in a for loop. I'm simply trying to grab the first number for the OS Version to differentiate between XP (5) and Win7 (6).

The following works fine by itself for querying a single machine.

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ('wmic /node:%machine% os get version') do @for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%b in ("%%a") do @set osver=%%b
echo %osver%
```

However once I attempt to put it in a for loop, I'm only getting a blank for %osver%

```
for /f %%G in (list.txt) do (
    for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=.," %%a in ('wmic /node:%%G os get version /format:csv') do @for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%b in ("%%a") do @set osver=%%b
    echo %osver%
) > results.txt
```

I'm assuming it's an issue with my skip/tokens/delims but I'm not sure how to figure out where exactly it's going wrong. Any variation on them that I've tried still results in a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're assuming wrong.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

So, I'd predict that `call echo %%osver%%` in place of `echo %osver%` would fix your problem.

OTOH, `echo %%b` would likely be easier and quicker.

---

```
for /f %%G in (list.txt) do (
 for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=.," %%a in (
  'wmic /node:%%G os get version /format:csv'
  ) do for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%b in ("%%a") do (
   set osver=%%b
   echo %%b
  )
 CALL echo %%osver%%
) > results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You also dont have to set %%b to osver, if you only need to echo the value of %%b you may as well echo %%b because on its own it is a variable that is available only to the method in which it was declared.. you only make an instance variable if you are planning on using it outside the for body ..

So you should probably stick to enabledelayedexpansion if you wana use it elsewhere ...

also you should enclose your statements with parenthesis to to avoid code mix up ....

Comment: How do you echo %%b by itself? echo %%b shows up as %b

Comment: You echo %%b only if you are working from a batch file,;, and single preceding % if you are working from the command line..